# python-docx numbering lists and multilevel lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

Is there a python-docx equivalent the following visual basic code? What is it? Pointers to the appropriate documentation or sample code would be great too.

```
With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(2)
    .NumberFormat = "%1.%2"
    .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
    .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLegal
    .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0)
    .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
    .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .TabPosition = wdUndefined
    .ResetOnHigher = 1
    .StartAt = 1
    With .Font
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = False
        .StrikeThrough = False
        .Subscript = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Shadow = wdUndefined
        .Outline = wdUndefined
        .Emboss = wdUndefined
        .Engrave = wdUndefined
        .AllCaps = False
        .Hidden = False
        .Underline = wdUnderlineNone
        .Color = wdUndefined
        .Size = 10.5
        .Animation = wdUndefined
        .DoubleStrikeThrough = False
        .Name = "Times New Roman"
    End With
    .LinkedStyle = "L2"
End With
```

The goal is to be able to assign a paragraph a style with the appropriately linked numbering so that I can then assign the style to the paragraph and get well numbered lists automatically.

Comment: I came across https://pypi.org/project/python-docx-ml/, but I have not tried it yet.